# how make a repository in bitbucket "anonymous"

Tags: bitbucket

If I create a repository ( let's be mercurial ) on BitBucket can I make this repository with anonymous access, so that everybody can clone and make pull request?

I've arleady created the repository, maked it with pubblic access, tryed to add a "default" user... but I need credential access to clone the repository.

Comment: How you are trying to clone the repository? Via command line? If yes, which command you're using? Via tortoisehg? If yes, which options did you choose?

Comment: Dose it matter? I've tryed both command line hg clone blabla and tortoise hg

Comment: Try doing: ``hg clone https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg`` it is an annonymous mercurial repository hosted on BitBucket, which seems to be what you want. Works fine on my machine (no user supplied, I've sandboxed it on a test user).

Comment: @RudyMatela is it the link of tortoisehg? I've arleady installed it. I want something to google code hosted in bitbucket...